# run sql update statement on multiple databases

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following SQL update:

```
UPDATE [Shop_Benelux_2012].[dbo].[StringResource]
   SET [ConfigValue] = ''
 WHERE [Name] = 'default.aspx.1'
GO
```

I have 10 databases i need to run this statement on.

My DB's look like this:

- Shop_DE_2012
- Shop_FR_2012 ...

how can i run the statement on all databases without manually running it on each db in management studio?

Comment: See e.g. [Red-Gate SQL Multi-Script](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-multi-script/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick and dirty

```
EXEC sp_MSForEachDB '
USE ?
IF DB_NAME() LIKE ''Shop%''
   UPDATE [dbo].[StringResource]
   SET [ConfigValue] = ''''
 WHERE [Name] = ''default.aspx.1''
'
```

Note: I use a 2 part name, without "Shop_Benelux_2012"

Comment: @Super2: just change the LIKE then to `Shop%2012`

Answer (score 0):

I have a view that wraps all databases together that allows me to select, insert, update, or delete from any of them with one query.  These are known as partitioned views.  You'll want to read this.

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190019(v=sql.105).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190019%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)